# Make remaining review numbers dynamic too

Tags: feature-request, review

The [review overview](https://stackoverflow.com/review) shows **dynamically** the reviewers in a horizontal list that change for every review. This is looking really cool. But does it contain useful information? Not really.

On the left side we see the numbers of remaining reviews. This is static. Does it contain useful information. Yes! I.e. it would prevent me from opening a queue that is already empty.

#### Please make the numbers dynamic too!! *

<sub>* This would also look really cool BTW.</sub>

[image: review overview]